# About trajectories on a circular billiard

Tags: billiards

Let consider a circular billiard.

You start by putting the ball on the edge off the table. The trajectory then is quite simple (see the picture), with equal angles at each rebound.[image]

Which will eventually gives a trajectory looking something like this:[image]

Let's call the angle between the center of the billiard, the starting position and the first rebound $\theta$.

We already know that if $\frac \theta \pi\notin \mathbb Q$ then the trajectory is dense on the edge of the billiard (that we call $\mathcal C$). We assume that $\frac \theta \pi\notin \mathbb Q$ from now on.

My three questions are:

> (1) If $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a finite family on $\mathcal C$, does it exist a dense trajectory which avoid every $x_i$ ?
>
> (2) If $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a countable family on $\mathcal C$ which is discrete on $\mathcal C$, does it exist a dense trajectory which avoid every $x_i$ ?
>
> (3) If $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a countable family on $\mathcal C$, does it exist a dense trajectory which avoid every $x_i$ ?

We obviously have $$(3)\Rightarrow (2)\Rightarrow (1).$$

I believe that (1) is true, I think (2) is true too, and I don't know about $(3)$ (but I would like to think that it is !).

What are your thoughts on the subjects ? How would your prove such a result ?

Comment: HINT: you mention that you already have an important result on $\pi\mathbb{Q}$, maybe you could use that?

Comment: Yes I could, but I don't know how to link that result to my question... It's one thing to have a dense trajectory, it's another to have a dense trajectory avoiding a given set

Comment: Reading your question, I assumed you had earlier demonstrated that  $\frac \theta \pi\notin \mathbb Q$.  HINT: Do you know what would happen to such a $\frac \theta \pi\in \mathbb Q$ ? Even more fundamentally, if I give you the start and the first rebound of a trajectory, do you have a formula to determine the second? The $n^{th}$?

Comment: Like I said in the question, we don't care for the case $\theta\in \pi\mathbb Q$, because the trajectory is finite so it is not really interesting here. And yes, I know the formula but it's not helping me because the dense set to avoid could be awfully complicated. I think a more theoretical proof is required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Every trajectory avoids a dense family** of $(x_i)$, and this set was stated in your question, because it is $\pi \mathbb Q$. This is why I insisted to know what you had already demonstrated.

For every trajectory, let's set $x_0$ as the origin of the circle, and associate each $x_i$ with its polar angle.

Thus, $x_0=0$, $x_1 \in [0,2\pi[$, and more importantly, because the billiard is round :

$\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \quad x_i=ix_1$ mod $2\pi$

This equality yields that the trajectory will come back to its starting point  iff $x_1/\pi \in \mathbb Q$, that we note $x_1 \in \pi\mathbb Q$  (because $\exists i,n \in \mathbb N^2$ so that $ix_1=2n\pi$ iff $\frac {x_i}{\pi}=\frac{2n}{i} \in \mathbb Q$)

Also, we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus $\pi\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and thus in $[0,2\pi[$, so its image by mod $2\pi$ is dense.

Thus **every** non-repeating trajectory avoids the family $\pi\mathbb Q$ mod $2\pi$ which is a denombrable, dense family on $\mathcal C$, which demonstrates $(3)$

By the way, every repeating trajectory has a finite set of values, so they also avoid a dense set of points, for example they all avoid the points $\mathbb Q$ mod $2\pi$

**2. Every countable family is avoided by a dense trajectory:**

As some comments point out, I might have misunderstood the question. So, if the point is to demonstrate that for any countable family $(x_i)$, a non-repeating suite exists, the approach would be to exhibit such a trajectory $(y)$ using the following argument :

Let $(y)$ be a trajectory, it will encounter an $x_i$ iff

$\exists k,i,n \in \mathbb N^3, ny_1$ mod $2\pi=x_i $ mod $2\pi\iff y_1=\frac{x_i+2k\pi}{n}$

As $\mathbb N^3$ is countable, the set of all $y_1$ for which $(y)$ encounters an $x_i$ is countable. As $[0,2\pi[$ is not, we can always find a $\hat y$ that is neitherin this set, nor in $\pi\mathbb{Q}$.

Then the $(y)$ trajectory defined by  $y_0=0$ and $y_1=\hat y$ is non-repeating, and will avoid all $(x_i)$

Comment: I believe the quantification in (3), (2), and (1) is universal.  You have proven a different statement, as if it were existential.  It is easy to construct countable sets no two elements of which are $\pi \Bbb{Q}$ commensurable, for instance $\{0, \sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: I had never considered this interpretation of the question. You're probably right, which is a whole other story to demonstrate

Comment: Like @EricTowers said, the quantification is universal, otherwise the question is trivial like you said and the demonstration is in the question... Sorry if the way I said it misled you.

Comment: OK I added the demonstration for the new interpretation, I used some of the same notations, so I did not delete my first proof. I tried to clarify the two parts in my answer.